# Is it possible to distribute a python class into different .py files and call them to a main.py file?

Tags: python, operating-system, python-import, modular-design

Is this what **modular programming** is all about?
I have recently started python intermediate programming and it's been advised to me to distribute all my functions into different files under the same class. I have tried but I'm running into various OS problems while importing. Basically it was a **C.R.U.D. operation** in python using sqlite3.

And so according to the above advice I need to make 5 different .py files. One for each of the operation and then a 5th one to display the database. Which means that I need to import 5 different files in my main.py file also while maintaining all the functions into a class of **CRUD**

So my question arises that this importing and maintaining the class doesn't that make it a hectic thing? If there is a better way to do it please advice me.

Folder structure for my program is below:

```
 ->services (folder)
   ->__pycache__ (folder)
   ->input_files (folder)
   ->output_files (folder)
   ->__init__.py
   ->add_crud.py
   ->read_crud.py
   ->update_crud.py
   ->delete_crud.py
   ->file_choose.py

-> __init__.py
-> crud.db
-> main.py
```

Thank you.

I tried importing every file into the main.py file but it always ran into trouble of could not find the file.
A snippet of my import in main.py looks like this:

```
from services import file_choose as fc
from services import insert_crud as ic
from services import view_crud as vc
```

Comment: " it's been advised to me to distribute all my functions into different files under the same class." That sounds like horrible advice.

Comment: New guys always run into bad teacher? What should I do now I wanted to learn from someone experienced

Answer (score -1):

```
from services import file_choose as fc
from services import insert_crud as ic
from services import view_crud as vc
```

According your snippet above,you tried import insert_crud and view_crud from services ,but there is no one file named insert_crud.py or view_crud.py in your folder structure for the moudle services bottom.

```
 ->services (folder)
   ->__pycache__ (folder)
   ->input_files (folder)
   ->output_files (folder)
   ->__init__.py
   ->add_crud.py
   ->read_crud.py
   ->update_crud.py
   ->delete_crud.py
   ->file_choose.py
```

maybe it is just a mistake,but if you want to import another package which is not in the services folder,try import it in `__init__.py`.

Comment: `services/insert_crud.py` exists according to OP, so I'm not sure what you are saying. (Maybe that `services` is not found in Python's search path?)

Comment: if the insert_crud.py is not complete or not ready to perform the operation will it not import things?